# Recognizing faces in a streaming video AWS - How to connect live video into Kinesis video stream?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, facial-identification

I am new to AWS.. Now I am ok with Recognizing faces in static images. I would like to Recognize faces in a streaming video.. I refer this link[enter link description here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/rekognition/latest/dg/recognize-faces-in-a-video-stream.html) But I don't understand how to connect the live video into kinesis video stream. Anyone can help me to understand the processor .

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the KinesisVideo-Rekognition integration samples in Kinesis Video github page. These samples demonstrate how to use Rekognition to recognize faces from live video stream.

https://github.com/aws/amazon-kinesis-video-streams-parser-library#kinesisvideo---rekognition-examples

1. [KinesisVideoRekognitionIntegrationExample](https://github.com/aws/amazon-kinesis-video-streams-parser-library#kinesisvideorekognitionintegrationexample) decodes H264 frames and renders them with bounding boxes locally using JFrame. To run the sample, run KinesisVideoRekognitionIntegrationExampleTest with appropriate inputs.
2. [KinesisVideoRekognitionLambdaExample](https://github.com/aws/amazon-kinesis-video-streams-parser-library#kinesisvideorekognitionlambdaexample) decodes H264 frames, overlaps bounding boxes, encodes to H264 frames again and ingests them into a new Kinesis Video streams using Kinesis Video Producer SDK.